# How to substitute a non-simple variable references in string

Tags: perl

Consider the following code:

```
my $msg='My name is $person->{name}.';
my $person={ name=>'Peter', gender=>'Male' };
```

So I want to print $msg. I've seen examples that resolve simple variable substitutions like '$name', but I haven't seen how to resolve my problem. I tried:

```
print eval $msg;
```

but that did not work (printed nothing). How can I print `My name is Peter.`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `eval` "does not work", it sets the special variable `$@` with the error Perl encountered while evaluating the expression. In your case, that message is

```
syntax error at (eval 1) line 2, at EOF
```

because the literal text

```
My name is $person->{name}.
```

can not be parsed as Perl code. But an easy fix is to enclose that text in quotes.

```
my $msg='"My name is $person->{name}."';
my $person={ name=>'Peter', gender=>'Male' };

print eval $msg;
```

Output:

```
My name is Peter.
```

Other ways to fix this program are to send quoted text to `eval`:

```
my $msg='My name is $person->{name}.';
print eval "\"$msg\"";
print eval qq/"$msg"/;
```

Comment: I would add a heavy caveat that string eval is a bad idea, and the input variables should at the very least be passed through quotemeta.

Comment: This is what I wanted. Thanks for the info re $@ storing the errors too. Very useful to know.

Comment: @Grinnz: Interestingly, `$person` can contain anything and will still be safe. `$msg`, on the other hand, is dangerous.

Comment: To be specific why it's a bad idea, `$msg = '@{[system rm ~/.bashrc]}';`

Comment: It is dangerous. The example I gave was a simplification of what I am actually trying to do. Rest assured, the `$msg` string will not be derived from user input (or any other uncontrolled data).

Answer (score 4):

You're inventing a templating system. Fortunately, it already exists: [Template](http://p3rl.org/Template).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Template;

my $msg='My name is [% person.name %].';
my $person={ name=>'Peter', gender=>'Male' };

my $template = 'Template'->new;
$template->process( \$msg, { person => $person }, \ my $output );
print $output;
```

Comment: Yes, I know. I was really trying to understand whether there was a way to specify the substitution using actual perl syntax.

Comment: There is, but only if the variable exists already when you create the double-quoted string. Otherwise you are talking about templating and should use a templating module. Some other options: [Text::Template](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Template), [Mojo::Template](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Template), [Text::Xslate](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Xslate)

Comment: Ah, but there's also eval - and now, thanks to @mob, I now know why it wasn't working for me. Thanks for pointing me at Text::Template, though - it might come in useful some time.

Answer (score 1):

It works when you declare the hash first.
Be sure to use double quotes:

```
my $person={ name=>'Peter', gender=>'Male' };
my $msg="My name is $person->{name}.";

print $msg;
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear in my original question. The value of $msg is not set to a string constant - that's why I enclosed the text in single-quote characters. The message needs to be evaluated at the time that it is used, not at the time that the string is assigned.

Answer (score 0):

It's always worth checking the Perl FAQ for answers to questions like this.

[How can I expand variables in text strings?](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-expand-variables-in-text-strings%3f)

Comment: Of course it is. But in this case, I did and it didn't provide the answer.

Comment: @pdac: But it does. The question I linked to gives exactly the information you need.

Comment: I don't think so (unless I missed something). This explains how to use regex substitution to evaluate simple names like `$name`, not how to deal with a hash ref like`$person->{name}`. That method will also destroy my original template. Using `eval` is the solution here.

Comment: @pdac: The second example in that FAQ uses a hash. And switching that to a hash reference is a trivial syntax change. And you can stop destroying the original variable by either copying it or using the `/r` option on the substitution operator. This approach is far safer than using `eval`.